# binary_search not working for a vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, vector, binary-search

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    string temp;
    vector<string> encrypt, decrypt;
    int i,n, co=0;
    cin >> n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
            encrypt.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        decrypt.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp = encrypt[i];
        if((binary_search(decrypt.begin(), decrypt.end(), temp)) == true) ++co;
    }
    cout << co << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It reads two equal lists of strings and should print out how many of the words in the first list are also found in the second list, simple.
Not giving me the expexted results and i think the problem is in binary_search. 
Can you tell me why ?

Comment: The input is:
first list :
hi
everyone
they
are
ugly
second list: 
they
pig
frog
ugly
are

Comment: Then the people who guessed that the input wasn't sorted were correct. But if you had given us the input as part of your question, we wouldn't have to guess. Always provide the maximum amount of information you can when asking a question here - some of us hate guessing.

Comment: Note that `binary_search` returns the result of whether an item is in the container.  To find the location of an item, use either `lower_bound` or `upper_bound`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the strings are not sorted in your vectors. Sort them first using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: +1. Note that if you're only looking *once* you should probably use std::find instead of std::sort and std::binary_search.

Answer (score 8):

collection must be sorted before doing `binary_search`. is it?

Answer (score 6):

Probably, your inputs are not sorted.  `binary_sort` requires you to sort, which you can do with [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/).  If order doesn't matter, a better approach may be to use a [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/), and the [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/find/) function

Answer (score 2):

`binary_search` assumes that your vectors elements are already sorted, lowest to highest. Are they?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you must use the `binary_search` with function created to compare strings.

For example, in your case:

```
if((binary_search(decrypt.begin(), decrypt.end(), **temp.c_str(),compareFunction**)) == true) ++co;
```

You must declare `compareFunction` in this way:

```
bool compareFunction(string aux1,string aux2)
{
  if(strcmp(aux1.c_str(),aux2.c_str()) <0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

you can see the declaration of this method [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/).